# Angular - confirmation token is not being passed to the textinput field from route

Tags: angular

In my Angular-12, I have this code:

Backend is Laravel.

backend:

```
public function toMail($notifiable)
{
    return (new MailMessage)
    ->subject('Confirm your account')
    ->line('Thanks for signup! Please before you begin, you must confirm your account.')
    ->action('Confirm Account', url('http://localhost:4200/signup-activate/'.$notifiable->activation_token))
    ->line('Kindly note that your email ('.$notifiable->email.')'. ' or mobile number (' .$notifiable->mobile_number.')'. ' serves as LoginID/Username')
    ->line('Thank you for using our application!');
}
```

component:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
    this.token = params['token'];
  });
}

onSubmit(){
 this.ngOnInit();
  if (this.token){
    this.api.get('signup-activate/'+this.token, null)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.tokenHandler(data);
      },
      error => {
        this.store.dispatch(loadErrorMessagesSuccess(error));
        });
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<form class="form-signin" #ResetResponseForm=ngForm (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
  <div class="form-label-group">
    <input type="text" name="token" id="inputtoken" class="form-control" placeholder="Enter Activation Token" required autofocus [(ngModel)]="token">
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase" type="submit" [disabled]="!ResetResponseForm.valid">Activate</button>
</form>
```

routing:

{
path: 'signup-activate/:token',
component: SignupConfirmComponent
},

When user clicks on the Email notification, I expect the token that appears to the route to be on the textinput. But the text field is blank.

[image: token]

How do I resolve this?

Or better still, how do I represent this:

```
http://localhost:4200/signup-activate?token=dffggg
```

on Angular routing:

{
path: 'signup-activate/:token',
component: SignupConfirmComponent
},

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, `ngOnInit` is a lifecycle look which is called at a specific stage in the component lifecycle. I strongly recommended `don't call it by yourself`.

You can use `ActivatedRoute` from routing module. Whenever the path is activated you will get the params if any. You should do something like this:

```
..
..
import { ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
..
.
.
.

constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

ngOnInit(): void {
    this.token = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('token'); // check the values if you are sending correctly or not.
  }

onSubmit(){
 // this.ngOnInit(); // remove this it will be called automatically check angular lifecycle hooks
  if (this.token){
    this.api.get('signup-activate/'+this.token, null)
    .subscribe(
      data => {
        this.tokenHandler(data);
      },
      error => {
        this.store.dispatch(loadErrorMessagesSuccess(error));
        });
   }
}
```

Another mistake is `http://localhost:4200/signup-activate?token=dffggg`. you are passing token as query string params and trying to expect it in params which you will never get. Try to change it to `http://localhost:4200/signup-activate/dffggg`.

You should check lifecycle hooks [here](https://angular.io/guide/lifecycle-hooks) and for more details how to get the param value you can check this [link](https://www.samjulien.com/how-to-use-route-parameters-in-angular).